# I just ran the command sudo apt update just like i do everyday but this time i got an error im new can someone tell me the exact command i can run?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

```
*E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Yes but can you tell me the exact command i can use?Sorry i am new to this. @Pizza

Comment: Your command would be `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`.  The `ubuntu-wine` PPA is deprecated and no longer used.  If you try to run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` to add it, it says that it is double deprecated and replaced by Wine Builds PPA.  The instructions to add Wine Builds are there.  Make sure that if you run that command to hit Ctrl+C so you don't re-add it.